# is it possible to use leaflet version 1 with custom mapbox style?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

This generates an error

> leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of
>   undefined

```
    <!-- Leaflet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.0-beta.2/leaflet.js"></script>
            <!-- Mapbox GL -->
        <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.3/mapbox-gl.css" rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.3/mapbox-gl.js"></script>


mapboxgl.accessToken = YOUR_KEY;
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: YOUR_STYLE_URL
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know that impossible, however Mapbox.js (built on Leaflet) supports style url's via `L.mapbox.styleLayer` since version 2.3.0:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN;

var map = L.mapbox.map('map').setView([38.97416, -95.23252], 15);

// Use styleLayer to add a Mapbox style created in Mapbox Studio
L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/emerald-v8').addTo(map);
```

See: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/stylelayer/

Comment: thanks a lot! I couldn't find it anywhere in the beta 2 doc.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was about using leaflet 1.0 with mapbox styles, so I'll answer that (though you accepted an answer for using mapbox.js) .

The new mapbox style studio raster tiles are 512x512 pixels.  You need to set up both tileSize and zoomOffset to make the tiles work correctly in leaflet.js , otherwise the tiles will look too small.

```
var myCenter = new L.LatLng(50.5, 30.51);
var map = new L.Map('map', {center: myCenter, zoom: 15});

var positron = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v8/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidHJpbGxpdW10cmFuc2l0IiwiYSI6ImVUQ2x0blUifQ.2-Z9TGHmyjRzy5GC1J9BTw', {
    tileSize: 512,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);
```

Here you can test it:  http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/moy/edit?html,output